# How to deal with "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setup' "

Tags: python-3.x

I installed the module "pyunicorn" in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and all the dependencies but when I import the module  in python 3.7.3 i get this error :

```
>>> import pyunicorn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyunicorn/__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    from setup import __version__
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setup'
```

---

What should i do to make it run properly???

---

Comment: how did you install pyunicorn?

Comment: By the command "pip install pyunicorn"  to my terminal. And before that , i did the same with the dependencies.

Comment: Since you're using python3.7, can you try ```pip3 install pyunicorn``` instead of ```pip install ...```?

Comment: I already did it... Nothing changed...

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. I wanted to install it on Google Colab. I tried installing pyunicorn directly from Github and it worked for me. Try using following instruction:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/pik-copan/pyunicorn.git#egg=pyunicorn
```